# Career messaging seems to broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

I am experiencing problems with the messaging. The messaging page gets loaded until it tries to fetch the messages (it looks like it doesn't matter which kind of message. For me, neither Applications nor Inbox is loading).So the only thing I see on screen is "Loading message list...".

I can reproduce this behaviour in Chrome and Firefox on Ubuntu 14.04. Chrome's dev console mentions the following error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token
    at Object.parse (native)
    at Y (https://cdn-careers.sstatic.net/careers/Js/third-party/angular/1.2.6/angular.min.js?v=72aaf3f547be:1:4691)
    at a.defaults.transformResponse (https://cdn-careers.sstatic.net/careers/Js/third-party/angular/1.2.6/angular.min.js?v=72aaf3f547be:2:778)
    at https://cdn-careers.sstatic.net/careers/Js/third-party/angular/1.2.6/angular.min.js?v=72aaf3f547be:2:502
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at o (https://cdn-careers.sstatic.net/careers/Js/third-party/angular/1.2.6/angular.min.js?v=72aaf3f547be:1:1004)
    at Vt (https://cdn-careers.sstatic.net/careers/Js/third-party/angular/1.2.6/angular.min.js?v=72aaf3f547be:2:510)
    at r (https://cdn-careers.sstatic.net/careers/Js/third-party/angular/1.2.6/angular.min.js?v=72aaf3f547be:2:1195)
    at c (https://cdn-careers.sstatic.net/careers/Js/third-party/angular/1.2.6/angular.min.js?v=72aaf3f547be:2:16271)
    at https://cdn-careers.sstatic.net/careers/Js/third-party/angular/1.2.6/angular.min.js?v=72aaf3f547be:2:16948 angular.min.js?v=72aaf3f547be:2
```

Do I miss something?

Best regards,
Holger

Comment: I'm not sure if this is related but there are/have been problems with the websockets.

Comment: Can you post the link to the message you're trying to open please? Don't worry, the only people that can open it are Careers mods (employees) and yourself.

Comment: Hi. For sure, but it also happens if I only click on the "Messages" link in the upper right.
Example link: http://careers.stackoverflow.com/users/349194/messages/540723

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry about that! A little mixup on our end. Should be all fixed now.

Comment: Perfect. I've just double-checked in on my smartphone and my desktop. It is working again. Thank you for the fix!